# MS project server 2016 The specified server may not support APIs used in this operation

Tags: c#, csom, ms-project-server-2016

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Cannot find stub for type with id "{154360b4-899f-4237-b0ed-3e35f014c748}". The specified server may not support APIs used in this operation.'

Crash on projContext.ExecuteQuery(), how solve this problem?

```
    private const string pwaPath = "project site";
    private static string projName = "project name";

    private static ProjectContext projContext;
    private static PublishedTask projTasks;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
        {

            projContext = new ProjectContext(pwaPath);
            //projContext.Load(projContext.Projects);
            projContext.ExecuteQuery();

            List<string> TasksID = new List<string>();

            foreach (PublishedProject pubProj in projContext.Projects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t{0} : {1}", pubProj.Name, pubProj.CreatedDate.ToString());
                foreach (PublishedTask item in pubProj.Tasks)
                {
                    TasksID.Add(projTasks.Name);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nProject ID : Project name : Created date");
            }

            Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit: ");
            Console.ReadKey(false);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Were you running from VS or from an application?  You cannot just take an application from VS and move exe to another PC.  It must be published and use the setup.exe folder to install on deploy PC.  To run on another PC, the PC must have same version of Net Library.  The publish install the missing (or updated) dll needed to run app.

Comment: We deploy solution to project server from VS.

Comment: See following.  It may help.  Could not find any closer anser : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2016/11/24/provisioning-site-collections-with-csom-in-sharepoint-2016/

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for response, but we did that already. Didn't help though